# linux cron job script

Tags: linux, cron

I have a text file containing these configurations, in this case, the dollar sign after `:*:` means enabled and then the `!` sign means disabled.
I need a cron job script that disables for example test2 user at a scheduled time.
Can anybody help me out?

```
admin:*:$5$RrwoZPdk.0Ldid3j$2uSEMReM7YB5CNEZELT1JpszTxLug5bX3BBgABViNR3
test1:*:$$5$W.8w54rHMtJImaAu$JqumZvrv59oWNjJXp592qf4GkXySdNpHzFC7x70VDb.
test2:*:$5$AQbWnl3q291mtZEe$gxjzJdKgIKXH0Z9fPprk72QfZmceCEtXSaoKKAK68ND
test3:*:!$5$OQdsG.I4tndWaP5m$XBRHRFm7OKEyB0XB3EUQq0zcpXN.XLuMZudjlDUzm/4
```

And i need a log.txt of these changes if is that possible.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This can be done using the `sed` command, something like this:

```
sed -i '/test2/ s/\$/!/' /your/file
```

This will replace the `$` for the `test2` user with `!`, `/your/file` being the file you would like to edit, then take that command and put it into a cronjob.

This is a handy tool to generate a cronjob: https://crontab-generator.org/

Comment: Using `sed` to modify the shadow file is a bad idea. That's what `passwd -l` and `passwd -u` are there for, respectively.

Comment: @tink I simply answered a question about a text file